# How to get confidence score from a trained pytorch model

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I have a trained PyTorch model and I want to get the confidence score of predictions in range `(0-100)` or `(0-1)`. The code below is giving me a score but its range is undefined. I want the score in a defined range of `(0-1)` or `(0-100)`. Any idea how to get this?

```py
conf, classes = torch.max(output, 1)
```

My code:

```
model = torch.load(r'best.pt')
model.eval()
def preprocess(imgs):
    im = torch.from_numpy(imgs)
    im = im.float()  # uint8 to fp16/32
    im /= 255.0
    return im

img_path = cv2.imread("/content/634282.jpg",0)
cropped = cv2.resize(img_path,(28,28))
imgs = preprocess(np.array([[cropped]]))
def predict_allCharacters(imgs):
    output = model(imgs)
    conf, classes = torch.max(output, 1)
    class_names = '0123456789'
    return conf, class_names[classes.item()]
```

Model definition:

```
class CNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CNN, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Sequential(         
            nn.Conv2d(
                in_channels=1,              
                out_channels=16,            
                kernel_size=5,              
                stride=1,                   
                padding=2,                  
            ),                              
            nn.ReLU(),                      
            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2),    
        )
        self.conv2 = nn.Sequential(         
            nn.Conv2d(16, 32, 5, 1, 2),     
            nn.ReLU(),                      
            nn.MaxPool2d(2),                
        )
        # fully connected layer, output 10 classes
        self.out = nn.Linear(32 * 7 * 7, 37)
    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.conv1(x)
        x = self.conv2(x)
        # flatten the output of conv2 to (batch_size, 32 * 7 * 7)
        x = x.view(x.size(0), -1)       
        output = self.out(x)
        return output    # return x for visualization
```

Comment: It depends on how `output` was generated. Can you provide some code?

Comment: @Berriel hey i have added the code can u chk it

Comment: The relevant part would be the definition of `all_char`, but I guess my answer should help.

Comment: Thanks for the reply can u chk it now i am still not getting it

Comment: As I thought, my answer does what you need. Check the modified version of `predict_allCharacters` in my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case, `output` represents the logits. One way of getting a probability out of them is to use the [Softmax](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Softmax.html) function. As it seems that `output` contains the outputs from a batch, not a single sample, you can do something like this:

```py
probs = torch.nn.functional.softmax(output, dim=1)
```

Then, in `probs`, each row would have the probability (i.e., in range `[0, 1]`, `sum=1`) of each class for a given sample.

So, your `predict_allCharacters` could be modified to:

```py
def predict_allCharacters(imgs):
    output = model(imgs)
    probs = torch.nn.functional.softmax(output, dim=1)
    conf, classes = torch.max(probs, 1)
    class_names = '0123456789'
    return conf, class_names[classes.item()]
```